# Has the United States ever been formally condemned by the United Nations?

Tags: united-states, united-nations

Presumably, due to its veto power, the United States has never been condemned by the UN Security Council, but has it has it ever been formally condemned by another UN governing body, like the General Assembly?

If so, what was it for? How did the US government react to the condemnation?

Comment: The veto power only works in the security council, not the general assembly

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The General Assembly has [regularly condemned the US embargo against Cuba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_embargo_against_Cuba#Critiques_of_embargo_laws_and_rules):

> The United Nations General Assembly has condemned the embargo as a violation of international law every year since 1992. Israel routinely joins the U.S. in voting against the resolution as has Palau every year since 2004 to 2008. On October 26, 2010, for the 19th time, the United Nations condemned the embargo, 192 to 2 with 3 abstentions. Israel sided with the U.S.

source [El Mundo](http://www.elmundo.es/america/2010/10/26/cuba/1288117911.html) (in Spanish):

> El documento logró un apoyo casi unánime de los 192 países que integran la ONU, ya que votaron a favor 187 miembros, en contra dos (EEUU e Israel) y hubo 3 abstenciones (Islas Marshall, Palau y Micronesia).

Answer (score 10):

The UN condemned the US for its invasion of Panama. From Chomsky.info:

> this was an act of direct aggression, and it was condemned by the United Nations,

source: http://www.chomsky.info/interviews/19900911.htm

> I don't think it equates with it exactly, but it was, the invasion of Panama was rather striking in that it was the first example of U.S. aggression or subversion in which there was no appeal made, there was no pretext that we were acting to defend ourselves against the Russians or their agents, and the reason was that at that point -- this pretext had never been credible -- but at this point it was beyond the imagination of anyone to invent it. In that respect, it was, we might call it, a post cold war invasion. Beyond that, there are similarities I should say. If -- this was an act of direct aggression, and it was condemned by the United Nations, the United States had to vote against both Security Council and General Assembly resolutions, the United States established a puppet regime which is dominated by U.S. so called "advisers" down to details.

Comment: Quoting Chomsky? His opinion "this was an act of direct aggression" is the opinion of a man who's career has been to troll. The fact "it was condemned by the United Nations" could be verified elsewhere. I don't mean to disparage Noam Chomsky's character, but presenting him as a neutral, reliable source of information is rather disingenuous regardless of one's agreement or disagreement with him.

Comment: You don't have to agree with the man but as he is just as much a man of science he references his sources. In fact, he himself recommends students of history to pay careful attention to the scientific as preparation to their study.

Comment: [A/RES/44/240](http://www.un.org/documents/ga/res/44/a44r240.htm) adopted by vote [75 for, 20 against, 40 abstaining](http://research.un.org/en/docs/ga/quick/regular/44) Dec 29, 1989.  [Here's the UPI/API story](http://www.deseretnews.com/article/78973/UN-ASSEMBLY-CONDEMNS-THE-INVASION-OF-PANAMA.html?pg=all).

Comment: @dotancohen *"presenting [Chomsky] as a neutral, reliable source of information is rather disingenuous"* . **Neutral**, certainly not, but **reliable** he is. Chomsky quotes his sources and I don't remember him ever been caught in stating anything factually wrong.

Comment: That would make another good question, whether Chomsky has ever, inadvertently or not, presented false evidence.